# SAPUI5 OData success and error message with sap.m.MessageBox

Tags: odata, sapui5, messagebox

In my SAPUI5 app I have an OData operation which works fine. Now I try to show a success message if a new entry could be created and an error message if not. This is my code:

```
oModel.create("/ImportHeaders", oData, null, 
    function() { 
        sap.m.MessageBox.success("Interaction successfully created!", {
            title: "Success",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    },
    function() { 
        sap.m.MessageBox.error("Interaction could not be created.", {
            title: "Error",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    }
);
```

This does not show any message box (equal if operation was successful or not). What do I do wrong?

---

**Update** to I.B.Ns answer. This code achieves that the success message shows up but although if no interaction was created? Any ideas?

```
oModel.create("/ImportHeaders", oData, { 
    success: function() { 
        sap.m.MessageBox.success("Interaction successfully created!", {
            title: "Success",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    },
    error: function() { 
        sap.m.MessageBox.error("Interaction could not be created.", {
            title: "Error",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you add breakpoints in the functions? If so, did it stop in the functions?

Comment: Please, check the API reference of the corresponding model. E.g. for V2: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Model.create method parameters are (sPath, oData, mParameters?), try this:

```
oModel.create("/ImportHeaders", oData, { 
    success: function() { 
        sap.m.MessageBox.success("Interaction successfully created!", {
            title: "Success",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    },
    error: function() { 
        sap.m.MessageBox.error("Interaction could not be created.", {
            title: "Error",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Well the message box pops up but it always shows the success message even though no interaction is created? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with no interaction? Where do you call de omodel.create?

Comment: It did not work until my application was deployed to the server where the data is created. Now it works fine!